# How to set width and height of Android canvas in pixels?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I need to create a canvas element with exact pixel size (500x500). How do I set width/height in px?

Comment: you can do this in the xml and set the height and use the px unit.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be applicable in your case, but this works for me

```
Bitmap animation = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), resourceId, mBitmapOptions); //Get a bitmap from a image file

    // Create a bitmap for the part of the screen that needs updating.
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(animation.getWidth(), animation.getHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
    bitmap.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

You have create bitmap of the size which you want. and then `Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);` 
This sets the canvas to the size of the bitmap

Answer (score -1):

just like view.height = 100, so this view's height is 100 in px unit